# Clipping in Matplotlib. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to clip shapes like circles and ellipses using clipping in Matplotlib, but there must be something I am missing..
Why doesn't this clip the circle in half?:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

clip_box = Bbox(((-2,-2),(2,0)))
circle = Circle((0,0),1,clip_box=clip_box,clip_on=True)

plt.axes().add_artist(circle)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis((-2,2,-2,2))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know why your code does not work, however, the following snippet works as you expect.

From my undestanding, clip_on is not related to applying a given clipping to a shape but wether the shape should clip in the display area.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle

rect = Rectangle((-2,-2),4,2, facecolor="none", edgecolor="none")
circle = Circle((0,0),1)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_artist(rect)
ax.add_artist(circle)

circle.set_clip_path(rect)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis((-2,2,-2,2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I notice that with this solution, the circle disappears when interactively zooming to an area completely contained within the rectangle. Is there any way to remove this behaviour?

Comment: @Eskil It works for me (Linux, Matplotlib 0.99.3): the circle is still displayed, however it overshot the figure display area...

Comment: Linux, Matplotlib 1.0.1 here. I see that the circle stays in some cases when zooming to an area completely within the box. Try zooming to a small area in the middle of the blue area however. For me the blue disappears then, which is somewhat annoying in my application.

Comment: I don't see anything in newer Matplotlib versions.

Comment: @C-3PO meanwhile multiple calls to `plt.axes()` stopped working. Example is fixed. Thank you for noting that.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with this, so here's my version :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox



# This is in PIXELS
# first tuple : coords of box' bottom-left corner, from the figure's bottom-left corner
# second tuple : coords of box' top-right corner, from the figure's bottom-left corner
clip_box = Bbox(((0,0),(300,300)))
circle = Circle((0,0),1)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis((-2,2,-2,2))
plt.axes().add_artist(circle)

# You have to call this after add_artist()
circle.set_clip_box(clip_box)

plt.show()
```

The two differences are that the box' coords are in pixels (?!), and that `set_clip_box()` only works after `add_artists()` (which is why `clip_box=clip_box` doesn't work). I'd love to know what should be configured to get this working in "axes units" instead.

For posterity, here's the hack I've used to troubleshoot this. It clips *everything*, including the plots, axes, etc :

```
for o in plt.findobj():
    o.set_clip_on(True)
    o.set_clip_box(clip_box)
```